# Probability of two exponential random variables take the same value

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $A$ and $B$ be independent random variables drawn from the exponential distribution with parameters $\lambda_A$  and  $\lambda_B$. What is the probability that $A=B$?

Comment: For independent continuous r.v.'s $A$ and $B$ P(A=B)=0$.

Comment: Could you post a link to the proof and make it an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent continuous random variables, then
$$
\mathsf{P}(X=Y)=\mathsf{E}[\mathsf{P}(X=Y\mid Y)]=\int \mathsf{P}(X=y)f_Y(y)\, dy=\int 0 f_Y(y)\, dy=0,
$$
where $f_Y$ is the pdf of $Y$.